# Local connectedness of Comb Space

Tags: general-topology

I am currently looking at local connectedness. In munkres, there's a lemma:

**A space $X$ is locally connected iff for every open set $U$ of $X$, each component of $U$ is open in $X$.**

As an example of a connected but not locally connected space, there's comb space, described as: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CombSpace.html.

Just looking at the picture, I am convinced that the space is not locally connected. However, I am not convinced that why comb space must satisfy the latter part of the proposition: for every open set $U$ of $X$, each component of $U$ is open in $X$.

Take $X$ to be comb space and let $U$ be the ((circled ball) $\cap X$). Then, $U$ has components:
$\cup_{i=0}^\infty U_i$, where $U_0 = U \cap (\{0\}\times [0,1])$, and $U_i = U \cap (\{1/i\}\times [0,1])$. Clearly, component $U_i$ is connected.

What open set $U$ should I take so that each component of $U$ is not open in $X$?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation of *every component of* $U$ *is open in* $X$ is *at least one component of* $U$ *is not open in* $X$. Thus, you don’t have to show that **no** component of $U$ is open in $X$: you just have to show that $U$ has at least one component that is not open in $X$. Here that component is $U_0$.

Comment: I see. Thank you Brian.

Comment: @JamesChung: You’re welcome.